# Is there specific mythological significance to the Dingli Cliffs?

Tags: poetry, myths, maltese-language, john-p-portelli

The poem "Cliffs" ("Irdumijiet") is part of a [collection available online](http://john-peter-portelli.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Cirasa-Text-Copy.pdf) by the Maltese-Canadian writer, poet, and academic professor [John P. Portelli](http://john-peter-portelli.com/about/). Written in 1973, and found on pages 40-41 (page 21 of the PDF) in the book linked above, it goes as follows (English translation from the original Maltese):

> Take off oh friend the century of greed!
> Distance yourself from the ennui and the noise of the 20th century!
>
> You seem accustomed to the petty noise
> and the unbridled haste of the cities!
> You were struck by the mythological twilight of Dingli Cliffs!
> Everyday, stuck right there to the mythology, there is me, oh friend,
> there I present audaciously my face
> to the scimitar moon
> to the mischievous steeple
> to the bell half sleeping
> which little by little
> lulls me asleep
> in my weird, reserved bed!
> All this oh friend struck you and inspired you!
>
> I feel my whole life drown in the mythological silence, friend,
> in this mysterious emptiness which ends
> only God knows where.
> Yes, oh friend, I am drowning.

**Is there a particular mythological significance to Dingli Cliffs?** I know zero about Maltese mythology, but the word "mythological" ("mitologiku") appears three times in this poem, and it seems like some of the phrases in the middle (scimitar moon, mischievous steeple, bell half sleeping, weird reserved bed) *might* be references to some local story.