# Has the Maltese poem "Fuq Għoljiet Dingli" ("On Dingli Cliffs") by Victor Fenech been ever translated into any other language?

Tags: poetry, translation, maltese-language, john-p-portelli, victor-fenech

I've been reading some of the poems of the collection *Ċirasa* (*Under the Cherry Tree*) by John Peter Portelli, [available at the author's website with a translation to English](http://john-peter-portelli.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Cirasa-Text-Copy.pdf).
I especially liked the poem *Irdumijiet* (*Cliffs*, page 40 on the above linked document), a text that makes me feel so close and at the same time so far from Malta and the Maltese people. There is a [question about this poem   by  Rand al'Thor](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/11660/) in this community, where you can read its translation to English.

The author mentions that these verses were inspired by Victor Fenech’s poem *Fuq Għoljiet Dingli* (*On Dingli Cliffs*), that you can find at the [library of the University of Malta website](https://www.um.edu.mt/library/oar/bitstream/123456789/41278/1/Anali%25C5%25BCi%25E2%2580%259970_it-tielet_kwartett_1970.pdf). I would like to read this poem. In addition, I believe that the contents of these verses may have something to do with
Rand al'Thor question about the mythological significance of the poem *Irdumijiet*.

Unfortunately, I don't understand Maltese. I speak Catalan, Spanish, Italian, English and French. I more or less understand Portuguese. So, I wonder: has the poem *Fuq Għoljiet Dingli* been ever translated from Maltese to another language? Research on the Internet shows me that there is a [poetry film based on this Victor Fenech's work](https://www.independent.com.mt/articles/2017-08-21/newspaper-lifestyleculture/Malta-Mediterranean-Literature-Festival-next-week-6736178064), but I don't know if this implies some kind of translation or paraphrase of the poem in English or in any other language.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Dingli Cliffs poem is mine; it was first published in Maltese in the book 'Analizi 70' and much later in English in 2017 in the book ['Journey'](https://horizons.com.mt/product/journey/) together with a drawing of the place by a very prominent local artist. Dingli Cliffs are a favourite haunt of mine and recently I published a new poem and a short story featuring the same place. I fell in love with the place when I was once Headmaster at Dingli Primary School for two years. John Portelli, who lived in Dingli but is now a professor at a Canadian university, is a friend of mine and a very good poet and novelist. What is your interest in all this?

Comment: Nice to see you here! Please check out our [tour]. Note that we're not a standard forum and all answers must focus on answering the question, thus I've removed some tangential commentary from your answer. You could also perhaps [edit] in citations/links to better support your answer.

Comment: What a pleasure to meet you here! This community has topic challenges and one of them was devoted to Maltese literature, so I tried to read some Maltese poetry. I'm really delighted to learn from the existence of this translation to English.

Comment: Thank you for stopping by our little site to answer this question about your work! I also asked [another question here](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/11660/17) about the Dingli Cliffs, after reading Prof Portelli's poem about them and wondering if it was inspired by any local myth or legend about that spot. You would probably be the best person to answer that question barring Prof Portelli himself - I'd be very grateful if you could take a look at it. Thank you again and welcome to the site :-)